# Async/Await in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await

I'm trying to utilize async/await in my React app. From what I've been reading in this code the function should run first and then the console.log will wait for the function to finish...

```
async postSelectedHandler() {
    await this.getInServiceVenues();
    console.log('Updated In Service 2: '+this.state.venuesInService);
}
```

Maybe I'm wrong but what I'm trying to do is make sure the function runs first before the console.log runs but it's still running asynchronously.

Code for getInServiceVenues...

```
getInServiceVenues = () =>{
    this.setState({ loading: true });
    let bodyInService = [];
    let iterationInService = 0;
    let RequestingNetworkOperatorList = [];
    let updatedVenuesInService = [];
    
    axios.post( '/propertymanagement/listVenues', bodyInService, 
    {
        headers: {}
    })
        .then( response => {
            if (this._isMounted) {
            this.setState({loading: false});
            this.setState({venues: []});
            const venuesInService = response.data.InServiceVenueList;
            let venueIdInService = null;
            
            bodyInService.push(venuesInService);
            
            bodyInService.forEach(val=>{
                    venueIdInService = Object.keys(bodyInService[0]);
                    //console.log(venueId);
                })
            if(this.state.venuesInService!==[]){
                    this.setState({venuesInService:[]});
                }
            venueIdInService.forEach(val=>{
                
                updatedVenuesInService = bodyInService.map(venueInService => {
                    return {
                        ...venueInService[venueIdInService[iterationInService]],
                        iterationInService,
                        RequestingNetworkOperatorList
                    }

                });
                
                this.setState({
                    venuesInService:[...this.state.venuesInService, updatedVenuesInService]
                });
                iterationInService = iterationInService + 1;
                
            })
            console.log('Updated In Service 1: '+this.state.venuesInService);
        }} )
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
            this.setState({error: true});
        });
    }
```

Comment: does that geInServiceVenues() return a promise? can we see the code of that function

Comment: can you show the code for getInServiceVenues?

Comment: Your code will wait for whatever promise returned in `getInServiceVenues()` to complete and then run the `console.log`.  Then `postSelectedHandler` will complete

Comment: Post has been updated with code for getInServiceVenues()

Comment: await only works if the function you call returns a promise

Comment: Your `getInServiceVenues` does not return a promise, that's why it is not working

Comment: If you await something that isn't a promise, such as a function that doesn't return a promise, you'll find that whenever the value of the expression following the await operator is not a Promise, it gets converted to a **resolved Promise**.  Meaning it won't  do something pathological like wait forever for something that will never happen, it'll just continue past the _await_.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, the function you are calling isn't returning a promise so that bit is essentially running synchronously.

Add a `return` to the beginning of this line:

```
axios.post( '/propertymanagement/listVenues', bodyInService,
```

and it should work.

You can also optionally convert it to use `async` and `await` too, which is functionally the same:

```
getInServiceVenues = async () =>{
    this.setState({ loading: true });
    let bodyInService = [];
    let iterationInService = 0;
    let RequestingNetworkOperatorList = [];
    let updatedVenuesInService = [];
    
    try {
      const response = await axios.post( '/propertymanagement/listVenues', bodyInService, 
      {
          headers: {}
      });
    
      // everything from your then()
    } catch (error) {
      // everything from your catch()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use await/async in you `getInServiceVenues` function, change the `then` and `catch` to a synchronous operation.

Instead of using `then` and `catch`, use try/catch block and return the result of axios and then you dont need to use async/await outside this function.

Something like the code below

```
getInServiceVenues = async () =>{
    this.setState({ loading: true });
    let bodyInService = [];
    let iterationInService = 0;
    let RequestingNetworkOperatorList = [];
    let updatedVenuesInService = [];
    
    try { 
        const result = axios.post( '/propertymanagement/listVenues', 
        bodyInService, {headers: {}})     
        if (this._isMounted) {
            this.setState({loading: false});
            this.setState({venues: []});
            const venuesInService = response.data.InServiceVenueList;
            let venueIdInService = null;
            
            bodyInService.push(venuesInService);
            
            bodyInService.forEach(val=>{
                    venueIdInService = Object.keys(bodyInService[0]);
                    //console.log(venueId);
            })

            if(this.state.venuesInService!==[]){
                    this.setState({venuesInService:[]});
            }
            venueIdInService.forEach(val => {
                updatedVenuesInService = bodyInService.map(
                  venueInService => {
                    return {
                        ...venueInService[
                            venueIdInService[iterationInService]
                        ],
                        iterationInService,
                        RequestingNetworkOperatorList
                    }
             });
                
                this.setState({
                    venuesInService:[...this.state.venuesInService, updatedVenuesInService]
                });
                iterationInService = iterationInService + 1;
                
            })
            console.log('Updated In Service 1:'+this.state.venuesInService);
    } catch(error) {
        console.log(error);
        this.setState({error: true});
    };
}
```